# Asp.net MVC 4 Bundling and Minification of directories

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, ignite-ui

I am currently creating a project using mvc 4.0 and IgniteUI..
I am trying to bundle all the files of ignite ui...
so i have set in the web config file this

```
 <system.web>
 <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
```

My bundlesConfig.cs

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace LicenciamentoMVC
{
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
        //BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        //bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").IncludeDirectory("~/Content/","*.css",true));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/cssFiles").IncludeDirectory("~/Content/CssIgniteUI/", "*.css", true));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jsFiles").IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/js/", "*.js", true));
    }
 }
}
```

and then in the view that i want i put this, in this case index.cshtml

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/cssFiles")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jsFiles")

<h2>Index</h2>
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

my file directory is like this:
Project

```
-Content
    --CssIgniteUI(Css files of igniteui)
    --themes(default theme css files of asp.net project)
    --Site.css

  -Scripts
    --js(folder containing the js files from igniteui)
    --all the files that come with the default theme of the project
```

When i try to open the Cliente Controler...it gives me error...
What am i missing?
The page doenst appear on the browser..i am using firebug to see the files...but nthing shows..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: The error being what, exactly?

Comment: sorry for the mistake, i have added the erro to the question,the page doesnt appear, im using firebug to see if the files are being passed..but nothing..

Comment: When you go View Source, you are certain the files aren't being included?

Comment: The css files appear , the js files dont, so if i remove the bundle to the js files, the page appear...so the problem is related to js files...if there are duplicated files , inside js folder there is a jquery.ui,js, and in another directory there is other jquery.ui...Could that be the problem?

Comment: Are you loading duplicate js files?

Comment: i have recheked , and no, there are no duplicate files...

Comment: Does IgniteUI require jQuery? If so, are you loading jQuery before the rest of the files?

Comment: it works if i add just one file of the folder...

Comment: in the _Layout.cshtm, in the end of the file there is this line of code      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

Comment: **Edit**: If jQuery is(!) needed before `RenderBody()` injects scripts then you would move that line to the top of _Layout.cshtml or render bundles inside `@section Scripts {}` in your View. You said if you don't bundle everything works. Double check the order of files in the resulting page. You could also try .Include() instead of .IncludeDirectory() as a last resort.

Comment: i moved the  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") line to the top of the _Layout, the same things happen, the page doesnt render...

Comment: Can you give us the error text? "The page doesn't appear" isn't really descriptive. There should be something in the browser/firebug console. Perhaps something like "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method <igControl>"? If so, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be missing jQuery UI as ASP.NET MVC4 only adds jQuery bundle by default.
The correct order of required resources for Ignite UI would look like so:

```
In _Layout.cshtml:
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

And then either directly below that or in the View wrapped in the scripts section:

```
@section scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jsFiles")
    <!--Ignite UI related script(control definitions) go here-->
}
```

Basically, jQuery + jQuery UI need to be loaded before Ignite UI scripts. You can see that in [Adding Required Resources docs](http://help.infragistics.com/doc/jQuery/2013.2/CLR4.0/?page=Adding_the_Required_Resources_for_NetAdvantage_for_jQuery.html) and pretty much any [sample](http://igniteui.com/), so I'd suggest you use those as a reference when getting started.

On a side note, including both jQuery UI CSS(the base theme included in MVC4 in "~/Content/themes/") is not necessary as [Ignite UI theme CSS file is custom a jQuery UI theme](http://help.infragistics.com/doc/jQuery/2013.2/CLR4.0/?page=Deployment_Guide_Styling_and_Theming.html) too.